# Windows 8 Metro Tiles not working in theme despite code being correct

Tags: windows-8, microsoft-metro, windows-store-apps, winjs

Set up Win 8 Metro Tiles as instructed on Microsofts - http://www.buildmypinnedsite.com but they just don't work for me. My site is http://themixtapesite.com

Here is my header code with the tags in place, all other tags for other things work, all my Apple related code works fine.

```
<head>

<meta charset="<?php bloginfo( 'charset' ); ?>" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no">

<meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">

<link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" href="http://assets.themixtapesite.com/images/touch-icon-iphone.png" />
<link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="72x72" href="http://assets.themixtapesite.com/images/touch-icon-ipad.png" />
<link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="114x114" href="http://assets.themixtapesite.com/images/touch-icon-iphone-retina.png" />
<link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="144x144" href="http://assets.themixtapesite.com/images/touch-icon-ipad-retina.png" />

<title><?php wp_title( '|', true, 'right' ); ?></title>
<meta name="description" content="<?php rb_excerpt('rb_excerptlength_widget', 'rb_excerptmore'); ?>">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0; 
maximum-scale=1.0; minimum-scale=1.0; user-scalable=0;" /> 
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" /> 
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black" /> 
<meta name="application-name" content="TMS"/> 
<meta name="msapplication-TileColor" content="#000000"/> 
<meta name="msapplication-TileImage" content="http://assets.themixtapesite.com/images/15024da5-9803-4120-af3f-e8b2636c5eba.png"/>
```

There doesn't seem to be anything wrong with the code, you view the source and its there, but Win 8 and microsofts site don't read any of the 3 tags, title, colour or image. Must be something to do with my theme, but what could it be?

Answer (score 1):

First off can you remove the extra viewport  tag. There is no need to have two is there?

Also your page seems to have unclosed tags. Maybe this is causing it not to show?

http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fthemixtapesite.com.

Fix those two then get back to me. I'm sorry but I'm too much of a noob to comment directly to you.

Comment: Neither of these things - try http://clean.seiceed.com its a clean version of this theme, on buildmypinnnedsite.com and it still doesn't work. Something in that theme stops Microsoft reading the meta tags, but it shouldn't its a bug on Microsofts end...

Answer (score 0):

For the `tileColor` and `tileImage` to show up you have to pin to the start screen it from the metro (tile) version of Internet Explorer ([ie9](/questions/tagged/ie9)+).

Comment: Hi Eric, thats the way it was tested, but also tested on Microsofts own site - http://www.buildmypinnedsite.com where you can do the same thing, but with this theme it just seems to ignore the meta tags and no one, including the theme dev can find a reason why that would be the case